# Can I ask this as a question on the main site: "Enough detail to identify this picture?"

Tags: discussion

In pandemic, family's flicking through old pictures. Because my first two questions here were closed and downvoted, I just wanted to run this draft by you before posting on main site. If this is OK, I'll post it.

I cut out my sibling's head from this picture, but does anyone know where this is? Is there enough detail to identify it?

[image]

Comment: This reminds me of my unanswered [identify this - Motel on Route 66 in California, 1963](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138938/motel-on-route-66-in-california-1963), where the only truly defining features that must remain today are the mountains in the background.  It would be an interesting project for the folks at Google if one could do a search by skyline.

Comment: Just to note that the OP did post on the main site and someone could identify it from the anchors behind the sibling. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157200/where-are-these-3-white-flagstaffs-in-front-of-a-commemorative-stone-river-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sibling's cut-out head is directly obstructing a large portion of the only distinctive objects in the picture, so what do you think about whether this is a good photograph to identify a location?

Somebody familiar with the area might be able to identify it from the non-obstructed parts, or from the landscape visible in the background. It's certainly much more plausible that somebody can identify this than your last photo. But I wouldn't have particularly high expectations, especially if you can't even provide basic context like the country it was taken in.